# Multi-select Drop-down filter AngularJS Logic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-grid

Thanks for taking the time to read my question. I am currently working on an AngularJS UI-Grid, I've implemented a Multi-select Drop-down Menu for the "First Name" column. However, I am having some issues understanding how to implement the logic like I did for the "Male" & "Female" column since this is multi-select. If someone could please help me on the logic with the example I have already created for the first column "First Name". At least some guidance would be appreciated. Thank you in advance! 
Also, you may notice the grid is broken, the Header row is stuck and not scrolling horizontally. This has been fixed!

Here is the Plunker!
https://plnkr.co/edit/cAiZOIBpYZgDpfwspABK?p=preview

Here is some of my Angular & HTML code!
I know my code is not very DRY, I will be refactoring my code shortly.

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>

    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-ui-bootstrap@*" data-semver="1.3.3" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/1.3.3/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
    <script data-require="ui-grid@*" data-semver="4.0.2" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-grid/4.0.2/ui-grid.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/1.11.8/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="3.1.1" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="bootstrap.js@*" data-semver="3.3.6" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!--LINK TAGS-->
    <link data-require="ui-grid@*" data-semver="4.0.2" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-grid/4.0.2/ui-grid.css" />
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@*" data-semver="4.0.0-alpha.4" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

 <body ng-controller="mainCtrl">

      <button id="filterButton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Filter Columns</button>

      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title"><strong>Filter Columns</strong></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                  <table>
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Column Name:</th>
                        <th>Filter:</th>
                        <th>Value:</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                      <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <!-- FIRST COLUMN ROW -->
                        <td>
                            <select ng-model="columnName" class="form-control" class="columnName">
                                <option></option>
                                <option>First Name</option>
                                <option>Last Name</option>
                                <option>Company</option>
                                <option>Employed</option>
                                <option>Gender</option>
                                <option>Country</option>
                                <option>DOB</option>  
                                <option>Age</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select ng-model="filter" class="form-control" class="filter">
                                <option>Equal to</option>
                                <option>Contains</option>
                                <option>in between</option>
                                <option>Not equal to</option>
                                <option>Greater than</option>
                                <option>Less than</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text">
                        </td>
                        <!-- FIRST COLUMN ROW -->
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                      <!-- SECOND COLUMN ROW -->
                        <td>
                            <select class="form-control" class="columnName">
                                <option></option>
                                <option>First Name</option>
                                <option>Last Name</option>
                                <option>Company</option>
                                <option>Employed</option>
                                <option>Gender</option>
                                <option>Country</option>
                                <option>DOB</option>  
                                <option>Age</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select class="form-control" class="filter">
                                <option>Equal to</option>
                                <option>Contains</option>
                                <option>in between</option>
                                <option>Not equal to</option>
                                <option>Greater than</option>
                                <option>Less than</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text">
                        <!-- SECOND COLUMN ROW -->
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <!-- THIRD COLUMN ROW -->
                        <td>
                            <select class="form-control" class="columnName">
                                <option></option>
                                <option>First Name</option>
                                <option>Last Name</option>
                                <option>Company</option>
                                <option>Employed</option>
                                <option>Gender</option>
                                <option>Country</option>
                                <option>DOB</option>  
                                <option>Age</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select class="form-control" class="filter">
                                <option>Equal to</option>
                                <option>Contains</option>
                                <option>in between</option>
                                <option>Not equal to</option>
                                <option>Greater than</option>
                                <option>Less than</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text">
                        </td>
                        <!-- THIRD COLUMN ROW -->
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                      <!-- FORTH COLUMN ROW -->
                        <td>
                            <select class="form-control" class="columnName">
                                <option></option>
                                <option>First Name</option>
                                <option>Last Name</option>
                                <option>Company</option>
                                <option>Employed</option>
                                <option>Gender</option>
                                <option>Country</option>
                                <option>DOB</option>  
                                <option>Age</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select class="form-control" class="filter">
                                <option>Equal to</option>
                                <option>Contains</option>
                                <option>in between</option>
                                <option>Not equal to</option>
                                <option>Greater than</option>
                                <option>Less than</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text">
                        </td>
                        <!-- FORTH COLUMN ROW -->
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <!-- FIFTH COLUMN ROW -->
                        <td>
                            <select class="form-control" class="columnName">
                                <option></option>
                                <option>First Name</option>
                                <option>Last Name</option>
                                <option>Company</option>
                                <option>Employed</option>
                                <option>Gender</option>
                                <option>Country</option>
                                <option>DOB</option>  
                                <option>Age</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select class="form-control" class="filter">
                                <option>Equal to</option>
                                <option>Contains</option>
                                <option>in between</option>
                                <option>Not equal to</option>
                                <option>Greater than</option>
                                <option>Less than</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text">
                        </td>
                        <!-- FIFTH COLUMN ROW -->
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                      <!-- SIXTH COLUMN ROW -->
                        <td>
                            <select class="form-control" class="columnName">
                                <option></option>
                                <option>First Name</option>
                                <option>Last Name</option>
                                <option>Company</option>
                                <option>Employed</option>
                                <option>Gender</option>
                                <option>Country</option>
                                <option>DOB</option>  
                                <option>Age</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select class="form-control" class="filter">
                                <option>Equal to</option>
                                <option>Contains</option>
                                <option>in between</option>
                                <option>Not equal to</option>
                                <option>Greater than</option>
                                <option>Less than</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text">
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <!-- SIXTH COLUMN ROW -->
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                  <a href="#">add filter</a>
            </div> 
            <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button id="applyButton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Apply Filters</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
<br>
<br>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <div ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-pagination ui-grid-exporter ui-grid-resize-columns ui-grid-selection ui-grid-move-columns ui-grid-edit ui-grid-pinning class="myGrid" ng-model="columnName">  
        </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

//ANGULAR CODE BELOW

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp.bootstrap",["ngAnimate",
 "ui.bootstrap", "ui.grid", "ui.grid.moveColumns", "ui.grid.edit",
 "ui.grid.selection", "ui.grid.resizeColumns", "ui.grid.exporter",
 "ui.grid.pagination", "ui.grid.pinning", "angularjs-dropdown-multiselect"]);

myApp.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', 'uiGridConstants', function ($scope, uiGridConstants) {

    $scope.example1model = []; 
    $scope.example1data = [{
        id: 1, label: "Cox"},{
        id: 2, label: "Lorraine"},{
        id: 4, label: "Nancy"},{
        id: 5, label: "Laura"},{
        id: 6, label: "Ana"},{
        id: 7, label: "Feli"},{
        id: 8, label: "Victoria"},{
        id: 9, label: "Relu"},{
        id: 10, label: "Cristi"},{
        id: 11, label: "Jacob"},{
        id: 12, label: "Mike"},{
        id: 13, label: "Minodoa"},{
        id: 14, label: "Daciana"},{
        id: 15, label: "Utu"},{
        id: 16, label: "Kyle"}
        ];

    $scope.example1settings = {
        scrollableHeight: '300px',
        scrollable: true,
        enableSearch: true,
        checkBoxes: true
    };
    $scope.gridOptions = {
        enableFiltering: true,
        enableFullRowSelection: true,
        enableSelectAll: true,
        enableGridMenu: true,
        paginationPageSizes: [25,45,65],
        paginationPageSize: 45,
        enableSorting: true,
        enableHorizontalScrollbar: 1,
        columnDefs: [
            {field: 'firstName', minWidth: 250, headerCellClass: 'blue',
                filterHeaderTemplate:'<div class="ui-grid-filter-container"><div ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="grid.appScope.example1data" selected-model="grid.appScope.example1model" checkboxes="true" extra-settings="grid.appScope.example1settings"></div></div>'},
            {field: 'lastName', minWidth: 250, headerCellClass: 'blue'},
            {field: 'company', minWidth: 250, headerCellClass: 'blue'},
            {field: 'employed', minWidth: 250, headerCellClass: 'blue'},
            {field: 'gender', minWidth: 250, headerCellClass: 'blue', 
                  filter: {
                  term: '1',
                  type: uiGridConstants.filter.SELECT,
                  selectOptions: [ { value: '1', label: 'male' }, { value: '2', label: 'female' }]
             },
             cellFilter: 'mapGender'},
            {field: 'country', minWidth: 250, headerCellClass: 'blue'},
            {field: 'dob', minWidth: 250, headerCellClass: 'blue'},
            {field: 'age', minWidth: 250, headerCellClass: 'blue'}
        ],
    };




 /*=========GRID OPTION========*/
    $scope.gridOptions.multiSelect = true;
 /*=========GRID OPTION=========*/

    $scope.myData = [
        {
            "firstName": "Cox",
            "lastName": "Carney",
            "company": "Enormo",
            "employed": true,
            "gender": "male",
            "country": "USA",
            "dob": "08/14/1992",
            "age": "25"
        },


$scope.gridOptions.data = $scope.myData;

     $scope.myData.forEach( function addDates( row, index ){
        row.gender = row.gender==='male' ? '1' : '2';
      });

}])

myApp.filter('mapGender', function() {
  var genderHash = {
    1: 'male',
    2: 'female'
  };

  return function(input) {
    if (!input){
      return '';
    } else {
      return genderHash[input];
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Please post your code!

Comment: Thanks for the response! I've posted my Angular Code please let me know if any additional is needed. Also, my Plunker has my full application provided.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to filter rows by check multiple 'Fisrt name' options?

One thing i can think of is you can do the filter by yourself.
You filter grid data every time you checked/unchecked an checkbox option, after filtering, you re-assign the data back to $scope.myData

Comment: Thanks for the response @huan feng. Yes, I would like to filter through my grid by what is being selected from the drop down menu. When you mean "do the filter by yourself" do you mean create a custom filter?

Comment: I mean you manipulate the data by you own logic, do not depend on the ui-grid,

Answer (score 0):

I believe this below link will be very much helpful for you and does your code optimizations as well :)

[Custom Filters - Single selection and Multi selection](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/306_custom_filters)

Comment: Thanks @GOK 

I've spent a lot of time on the UI-Grid website and the "Custom Filter" section, however, I'm having a hard time understanding how to implement that logic to mine. They are using a Modal and a filter button which is what I guess is messing me up. If I can get more clarity on how I can implement that same method to my grid without the Modal and its custom template, the custom directive, and filter button, would be great!